# How to set > operator in the andFilterWhere

Tags: yii2

How to correctly add into the andFilterWhere method more or less operand?

```
andFilterWhere(['user_id' => 1]) - here I need to add > operand
```

Answer (score 2):

If the argument you pass into `andFilterWhere` is an array with 0-based indexes the first item in array is treated as operator and others as operands.

So if you want to use `>` comparison you can do it like this:

```
andFilterWhere(['>', 'user_id', 1])
```

See the documentation for [`yii\db\QueryInterface::where()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail) for more details.